# how to make hover effect last longer even after removing mouse

Tags: html, css

i am trying to make a home page for my browser
when i hover over stackoverflow many others divs(clickable links) become visible
but when i move my mouse to click over them the hover state is undone and i am unable to click them does anyone can give me general idea of how to deal with it , i want to make the hover affect stay even after removing the house for some time
[image]

```css
.wrapper{
border:1px solid red;
}
label#stackoverflow:hover ~ a 
{
opacity: 1;
height: auto;}
a{
                    transition: all 5s ease;
                    opacity: 0;
                    height: 0;}
```

```html
        <div class="searchcontainer">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <label 
                id="stackoverflow" for="stackoverflow"><img            
                    name="stackoverflowask" 
                    class='selector' 
                    src="./assets/Stack_Overflow_icon.svg"><span
                    class="stack black">stack</span><span 
                    class="overflow black">overflow</span>
                </label></br>
                <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask">
                    <label 
                    id="substackoverflow"><span 
                        class="ask black">Ask </span><span class="question black">Question</span>
                    </label>
                </a></br>
                <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions">
                    <label 
                    id="substackoverflow"><span 
                        class="see black">See </span><span class="question black">Question</span>
                    </label>
                </a></br>
                <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/14266024/infinity">
                    <label 
                    id="substackoverflow"><span 
                        class="look black">Look At </span><span class="question black">Profile</span>
                    </label>
                </a></br>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Put the a tag inside the label tag, `label:hover a { opacity: 1 }`, might be better to go with a UL > LI structure if you're really bothered

Comment: i was making it just for myself so it doesn't really matter if i use wrong tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines should point you in the right direction.

When the `a` tag is inside the `label` tag, you are technically still hovering over the label when your cursor is over it's children.

```css
a.subitem { 
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

label:hover a.subitem {opacity: 1}
```

```html
<div>
    <label>Stackoverflow <a class="subitem" href="#">SomeLink</a></label>
</div>
```

Comment: for anyone trying to understand this dude wrapped the link inside a container
and put the hover effect on the label instead of links itself